# When to use Open Id Connect?

Tags: ionic3, jwt, openid-connect, lexikjwtauthbundle

I'm building an app (front : ionic, php/symfony for backend) where I use jwt token to give access to backend, with LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle.

I was following an ionic tutorial to build a simple login form (https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-an-ionic-app-with-user-authentication) where I read about OIDC, and i'm a bit confused.

Should I use it instead of my actual way of authentication ? Or it should be considered only if I have to share access between multiple apps with an SSO ? Which is not my case.
.. Or maybe they used OIDC in the tutorial to be simple and go straight to the point.

Comment: You must use OIDC only if you need to connect multiple applications to one point.

Comment: thank you for your response

Comment: I'm implemented OIDC in my system, I'll tell you that this is an extra job, if you have no more than 1 application. If there are questions, you can contact. I'm use NodeJS + Angular + OIDC-provider (lib).

Comment: I will  thank you :)